# Is it possible to turn the following continuous?

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $g\left( {a,b,c} \right) = \frac{{\left( {1 - \cos ab} \right)\sin ac}}{{{a^3}{b^2}}}$ for $ab \ne 0$.

Is it possible to make this function continuous on ${\mathbb{R}^3}$

My preliminary trial using taylor series suggests yes but I am not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly continuous for $ab\ne 0$ so the question is how to define it on (0, b, c) and (a, 0, c).  I would rewrite it as $c\frac{ sin(ac)}{ac}\frac{1- cos(ab)}{(ab)^2}$.